# Asking question - not giving code, just link to production page

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)

Question in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449578/jcarousel-vertical-with-auto

Is it allowed? When it's answered, destination page is updated (most probably). And therefore question is outdated and invalid.

In general, should questions like this be closed on sight?

Comment: Hopefully the eventual answer is better documented than the question.  They usually are.