# Are "live collaborative" online pastebins/compilers acceptable for use in a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should we deal with questions that have broken links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99228/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-that-have-broken-links)

Refer to this question (visible only to 10K users): ["why does finding max height of a tree behave differently on different compilers?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946286/why-does-finding-max-height-of-a-tree-behave-differently-on-different-compilers)

The OP used what's apparently a pastebin/online compiler tool on a site called [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/) which has a "live collaboration" feature (think: Google Docs but for code instead). [This is the link](http://rextester.com/live/ZNTGEC35277) the OP provided in the question.

Immediately I can see a few problems with this. The fact that other people can edit the code in the "live collaboration" means that there is a real possibility that the code will be "out of sync" with the question, making the code sample useless. The site provides no revision history or anything like that, so I have no idea if the code is the actual code the OP is having trouble with or has been modified to something very different by somebody else in the meantime.

The question has since been deleted, but for future reference, what is the policy involving these kinds of "live collaborative" pastebins? Should I edit the question and include the entire code snippet in the question itself?

Comment: Dead links are the same as live links that change by the time you load the question

Comment: @random: Good point. I didn't think of it like that.