# Should I remove link and put screen shots instead in editing?

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)

In CSS related questions people put links to sites to show what they want to do. In some cases links are not required only providing a screen shot is enough. So my question is "*Should I remove link from such a question and put a screen shot or leave it as it is and comment author to do this?*"

Example of such a question is: [Headlines with icon images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388370/headlines-with-icon-images)

Comment: If the link isn't there, is the question NARQ? Then yes. And still too local in most cases.

Comment: @random: What do you mean by **NARQ**?

Comment: Incomplete. Details missing. If the link is useless, are you missing a large chunk of information to process the question accurately.

Comment: @HarryJoy: "Not A Real Question" its a close reason.  Also, its fun to say "you should NARQ on that question."