# SE policy for NSFW links in questions?

Tags: discussion, policy

A question was asked on StackOverflow about a javascript error on a page from a NSFW site. The page itself was fine, but the rest of the site was something along the lines of an artful nude gallery.

I was just wondering what the SE policy is towards things like this. I simply put `[NSFW]` after the link for the time being.

Comment: Oh, and next time, add a link to the [question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146583/ie7-throwing-an-error-in-jquery-1-7-1)... Not everyone will bother trying to look for it.

Comment: Isn't any question that needs a reference to a third-party site simply too localized by definition? Even worse: once that specific page is fixed, the question itself is of no value at all to future visitors.

Comment: @Arjan has the key point here. See [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978)

Answer (score 6):

The link was to the [contact page of the site](http://cindytest.abito.ca/contact/), which only has a contact page (duh). You'd have to explore the site on your own to get to the possibly nsfw content.

It's an extra click, which more or less is the same effort required to visit any link, and then write something nsfw in the address bar and let Google do the trick for you. I don't really think there is any point in having a policy over such links, unless, obviously, the link is to a site that has extremely offensive content - think: [unicorn haters](http://ihateunicorns.ytmnd.com/) [NSFW].

Comment: Well I meant in general. For instance, had the link been directly to a NSFW page, what then?

Comment: @Walkerneo Depends on the link, really. In this instance, even if the link was on the galleries, well, all you see is thumbnails, you still need to click through. Now, if it was directly to one of the larger images (assuming the problem OP had was in one of those, and they were linkable), then I'd say you could have accompanied your edit with a flag for moderator attention (and let them deal with it). I don't have a problem with the edit you made, but I don't really see a point to it. If people start linking to actual nsfw sites, let's cross that bridge when we come to it.

Answer (score 3):

SE shouldn't need to have a policy about this, it is common sense. If the OP has not included a warning in the text of their question then it is up to a fellow community member (i.e. you) to edit the post and add it.

I'm not sure of the usefulness of using only the [nsfw](/questions/tagged/nsfw) tag though. It is easily missed, and the warning should be near the link. Using a tag would mean the post would be searchable by that tag, which may be good or bad (should a legitimate question be 'tainted' by tagging it with nsfw?).

Comment: OP didn't use a tag, did exactly as you suggest, added `[NSFW]` right after the link.