# The [nsfw] tag is pointless. Can we kill it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, meta-tags

We currently have a [nsfw](/questions/tagged/nsfw) (which means "not safe for work", in case you were wondering). This contains three questions which should be closed as too localised:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/4386639/209139
- [Cannot remove extra margin/padding between divs even though reset.css used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7760760/209139)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/2478407/209139

And one question which possibly actually is not safe for work, if your workplace is riduculously strict, but which could easily be rewritten in a more generic fashion. (I'll do that myself if someone tells me it's a good idea.)

- [MySQL Search Refinement (replace long regex with subquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1026970/209139)

After those are cleared up, could we please get rid of this tag?

Comment: This is explicitly a meta-tag. Burn it.

Comment: `Four questions with tag ==> remove from all four questions`.  Tag disappears after 24 hours.

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Well, I just flagged the three for closure. I'll rewrite the one decent question to be more generic and less NSFW, and remove the tag while I'm at it.

Comment: Completed.  I need a shower now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole concept of tagging a question as nsfw is flawed.

I agree with [@HodoHod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164679/146015) that it should be burninated, but I disagree with the *"body of a question"* reason.

NSFW (AKA "acceptable use") policies and definitions are too diverse to make that tag worth the pixels on the screen. If a post contains profanity it should be removed. However, profanity is just one of the things that can make something NSFW - what about [subject matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164660/are-drug-related-terms-in-code-nsfw-and-or-frowned-upon-on-stack-overflow)? If you can't adequately define the tag, then it shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

I say burn it. The body of a question should never be NSFW, and any links can be demarcated as such by the OP.

See also: [SE policy for NSFW links in questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121312/se-policy-for-nsfw-links-in-questions)

Answer (score -4):

It's important to identify those questions that we don't want to open up at work.  It has a purpose.

Comment: If you're ever uncertain about the content on the site, then please refrain from using your work laptop to look at potentially NSFW comments.  :P

Comment: It's the tag that would give me the uncertainty I need to make that decision.