# Should I use Pastebin?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)

Is it good practice on Stack Overflow to post links to code in Pastebin, or should I just include the code in my post?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate.