# Add a " Provide context for links" section to the "How to ask" site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help

I think it would be a good idea to also have a "Provide context for links" section at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), like the one on [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

> **Provide context for links**
>
> A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there . Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

An original poster of a question could then be directed to this page in the comments, when he [includes an external link instead of showing his code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code).

Do you also think this would be a good idea or would it blow the help to much?