# which StackExchange forum should I ask CSS questions specific to html and Internet Explorer?

Tags: discussion, design, internet-explorer-8

I have a styling issue on our company's intranet that I can't figure out.
It only happens with IE8 or lower.  IE 9/10, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera are all OK.

I don't really know which StackExchange site to ask browser specific CSS questions though.
Which one should I use?

The issue is a border and paddings are appearing even though I've used `border:none;` and `padding:0!important;`

[image: border issue]

Comment: I think StackOverflow is OK

Answer (score 3):

Ask on Stack Overflow.

However: **Include relevant HTML and CSS code in your question.** Do not just link to your website and ask people to investigate it. See this meta discussion: [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978/152515)

Pointing to your website isn't that great because Stack Overflow exists to be a repository for knowledge, not so much a troubleshooting service. If the only example of relevant code we have is on your web page (where the broken code will be fixed within days, and the page itself may change completely within weeks), there's no value there for the future.

If you can't do that, and *really* all you can do is link your site and ask what might be wrong with it, that is not a good question for Stack Overflow.