# Where should browser version specific questions in the context of CSS be asked?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Today someone mentioned [a question I asked a couple years back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23370966/1992129) should actually be on Super User. However, I found a previous question currently on Meta showed [Stack Overflow was the correct place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201943/251626). The Meta question linked did not have much justification of Stack Overflow verses other sites, hence why I am asking it again with more contrast.

The argument being made for it to be on Super User is:

> if you are asking about specific CSS syntax in the context of Chrome 34, then I would argue it's an issue regarding software

Which I partially agree with after reading Super User's [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) page.

However, in web development, it's a common thing to run into vender prefixed CSS rules (making it more of a [Stack Overflow on-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) during software development. This is linked, for better or worse, to specific syntax for specific versions of browsers. These prefixes exist(ed) for users/browsers to experiment with features in development. Some browsers now have experimental flags or settings to get around that vender prefix now, which arguably is similar to vender prefixes (without exposing end users to experimental code).

At the end of the day, where's the right place for questions on CSS specific to versions of browsers? Additionally, why is that the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your situation is simple: you have code which doesn't work and you want to make it work. It doesn't matter if it doesn't work at all or if it doesn't work only in a specific browser. Stack Overflow is definitely the best place to ask such questions.

If you browse Stack Overflow questions tagged with the [css] tag and a browser tag (for example [[css] and [google-chrome]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome%20css?mode=all)) you will find many questions similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this makes sense to me. I'm going to leave unchecked for the moment in hopes this gets more attention/feedback.