# How to encourage people to use jsfiddle and pictures

Tags: discussion

I don't have a perfect solution, but I think we should encourage people to use more jsfiddle and images. With respect to the former, this is especially so with new users who ask questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811791/html5-canvas-and-jquery/8813996#8813996). For me to test this, I have to go to jsfiddle and set up a whole html environment with a canvas. It's not mission impossible, but it's something that would be easier for the OP to have done in the first place.

Also, I find questions with pictures are somewhat more attractive/useful:

- [Exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218429/654789)
- [Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219104/654789)

Comment: Also: [Make askers aware of JSFiddle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68467/make-askers-aware-of-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 11):

Your questions should stand alone, without linking to transient off-site resources which may eventually go away and leave your post broken. We shouldn't be encouraging their use; Questions which degrade into a series of revisions to a jsfiddle are *useless* and should be closed as too localized.

Comment: I agree that does quite often happen with both jsfiddle and images, but it' equally frustrating when someone shows one line and asks why their whole code breaks down.

Comment: The solution is that people should post their code on Stack Overflow (appropriately cut down to the bare essentials), and then (optionally) also link to a jsfiddle - if they want to save answerers time and thereby maximise their chances of getting an answer.

Comment: http://sscce.org/